# Upgrade / Update existing Ghost installation on Openshift from 0.5 to latest

Tags: openshift, blogs, redhat, ghost-blog

I know there's another thread but it's about 0.4.2 to 0.5 and there's a quickstart for 0.5.
What I want to do is install the latest version of ghost because there are some great features in the newer versions.

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: I want to upgrade from 0.5 to latest version of Ghost.
I tried once but failed.

Comment: I've tried and ghost's guide. And I've messed up my blog/overstuffed it. Had to reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: https://ghost.org/forum/installation/16533-resolved-upgrading-ghost-0-5-to-0-5-2-on-openshift/
Thanks fuzzmz.

- Set up a new installation using: `rhc app create test nodejs-0.10 mysql-5.1 --env NODE_ENV=production --from-code https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-ghost-mysql-quickstart.git`
- Go to URL/ghost and setup the admin user.
- Download latest Ghost [archive](https://ghost.org/download/).
- Extract archive.
- cd to the test folder.
- delete `index.js` and `package.json`.
- delete the `core` folder.
- delete the `content/themes/casper` folder.
- copy `index.js`, `package.json`, the `core` and `content/themes/casper folders` from where you extracted the archive to the test folder (the git repo created when I created the OpenShift app).
- modify the new `package.json` (the one in the test folder) with `"main": "index.js"` instead of `"main": "./core/index"`.
- `git add --all`.
- `git commit -am "update to ghost v0.5.2"`
- `git push origin master`

Comment: How about to update `node_modules` from which the ghost depends? Your algorithm is not update them, only ghost code. This may lead to malfunction!

Comment: Hey! Please, expand your answer and add how to update `node_modules` for ghost core.

Comment: please add:

replacing 'npm-shrinkwrap.json'

And doing a 'rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean && npm install --production '

Answer (score 0):

I went with the similar issue and solved it.

Follow this guide to update your ghost version.

1. Download the latest version of Ghost from Ghost.org
2. Extract the zip file to a temporary location
3. Delete existing `index.js` and `package.json` then copy new `index.js` and `package.json`  files to the same directory.
4. Next, delete the old "core" directory completely, and then put the new core directory in its place.
5. For releases which include update to Casper (the default theme), delete the old `content/themes/casper` directory and put the new one its place.
6. Finally open "package.json" and change `"main": "./core/index"` to `"main": "index"`

That's the tricky part that not mentioned on the official guide. It works fine :)

Run npm `install --production`
Finally, Restart Ghost so that the changes take effect